# How can I set global variable in drools using drools-spring and use same in DRL file

Tags: java, spring, drools

Basically I want to store a class reference as global variable from spring service class and use the same inside the DRL file to access method and properties of global reference.

Comment: What have you tried and failed? see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your service class use below code:

```
StatelessKnowledgeSession knowledgeSession;
CustomClass reference;
knowledgeSession.setGlobal("global1", reference);
knowledgeSession.execute(fact);
```

Inside DRL file

```
import CustomClass;

global CustomClass global1
```

Use reference inside any rule.

Comment: You omitted the keyword `global` from the DRL declaration.

Comment: Typo. global is required.

Answer (score 2):

you have to set the object ref into the kieSession as below

```
kieSession.setGlobal("serviceName", serviceRef);
```

and in your drools file import the global reference

```
global com.example.Service serviceName
```